# CloudFunction as gradle subproject

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-functions

I would like to deploy a CloudFunction which is defined as gradle subproject.

```
parent/build.gradle.kts
parent/cloudfunction/build.gradle.kts
```

It seems that the deployment copies the child `build.gradle.kts` to `workspace/` folder and ignores the parent build script. The build then fails with strange errors like:

```
e: /workspace/build.gradle.kts:7:5: Unresolved reference: implementation
e: /workspace/build.gradle.kts:8:5: Unresolved reference: implementation
e: /workspace/build.gradle.kts:9:5: Unresolved reference: implementation
```

I guess that is because the java, jvm and other plugins/setup are defined in the parent build script.

So I wonder – is there a way to overcome this? I would very much like to avoid duplicating the parent build script contents - which is exactly the point of having parent build script - to avoid duplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass directly compiled and shadowed JAR instead of letting the `gcloud` compile it itself.

> You can deploy a pre-built JAR that contains the function. This is useful especially if you need to deploy a function that uses dependencies from a private artifact repository that cannot be accessed from Google Cloud's build pipeline when building from source. The JAR can be an uber JAR that contains the function class and all of its dependency classes, or a thin JAR that has `Class-Path` entries for dependency JARs in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Sample to deploy JAR in Cloud Funtions:

```
gcloud functions deploy jar-example \
   --entry-point=Example \
   --runtime=java11 \
   --trigger-http \
   --source=build/libs
```

The following is described in *Deploy from a JAR* section:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-deploy#deploy_from_a_jar